# ¿Porque no funciona un condicional y ejecuta la peticio AJAX?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un codigo en el que compruebo si el idcliente en un input fue introducido.De ser asi si esta chequeado cuenta corriente lo anota a cuenta y sino es porque fue cobrado en el acto.

Pero antes tengo un condicional, donde si el codigo de cliente no ha sido introducido no haga nada.

```js
 $("#canilla1").click(function(event) {

 $("input[value=Confirmar]").click(function(){
        
      var id = $(this).attr("id");

  
      var cliente = $("#codcli").val();
      
     if (cliente!==""){
        
        
      if ($("#cc").attr("checked",false)){ 
      pago="s";
        $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"cc","cliente":cliente,"idpg":id,"fecha":fecha,"hora":hora,"pago":pago},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
               window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
            }
            });
      } else if ($("#cc").attr("checked")){
         pago="n";
        $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/venta/procesoventa.php",
                data:{"accion":"cc","cliente":cliente,"idpg":id,"fecha":fecha,"hora":hora,"pago":pago},
      

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
               window.location.href="index.php?controller=venta&action=index";
            }
            });
      } }else {alert("ingrese el cliente");}
 
});});
```

Pero el caso es que ejecuta las consultas ajax de igual manera.

Comment: creo que es por el if(cliente !== "") cambialo  if(!$("#codcli").val()) or (!$("#codcli").val().length === 0)

Comment: Ya verificaste que la variable `cliente` tenga datos?

Comment: esta condición siempre te dará TRUE --> if ($("#cc").attr("checked",false)) el hecho es que estas asignando un valor al attributo y te lo detecta como true en caso de que se asigne correctamente el valor.

Comment: si..si escribo algo contiene lo que escribo y sino vacio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que te esta saltando la validacion del cliente son los operadores de comparacion, sugiero que utilices Desigualdad (!=)

Desigualdad (!=)    Devuelve true si ambos operandos no son iguales.

Estrictamente desiguales (!==)
Devuelve true si los operandos no son iguales y/o no son del mismo tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Para validarel valor del campo del ID puedes con `$.trim( id )` ejemplo:

```
var id = $('.input').val();

if( $.trim( id ) ){
  // true
} else {
  // false
}
```

Para validar el checkbox puedes con `$.('.checkbox').is(':checked')` ejemplo:

```
if( $.('.checkbox').is(':checked') ){
  // true
} else {
  // false
}
```

El codigo completo y funcional debería ser asi...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $( '#send' ).click(function( event ){
  
    if( event ) event.preventDefault(); // Evita refrescar
  
    var clientID = $( '#client' ).val();
    
    // Con trim eliminamos espacios en blanco
    // Comprobamos que no tenga un valor:
    // TRUE: mostrar alerta
    // FALSE: nuna se ejecutará el codigo dentro de { ... }
    if( $.trim( clientID ) == "" ){
      alert('Introduce la ID del cliente');
      return;
    }
    
    // Con .is(':checked') Comprobamos si esta marcado o no 
    var CC = $( '#cc' ).is(':checked');
    
    if( CC ){
        
      // Hacemos un ajax si es correcto
      // Aqui deberia estar el ajax de tu codigo
      // con tus parametros
      // Esto es solo un ajax de prueba
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ){
            $('.reponse')
            .html('') /* Reseteamos*/
            .append('<p>CC es activado</p>')
            .append('<p>'+ clientID +' es la ID del client</p>')
            .append('<p>Respuesta del AJAX:</p>')
            .append(JSON.stringify( response ))
        }
      })
    
    } else {
      /* Si CC NO ES ACTIVADO */
    
       // Hacemos un ajax si es correcto
      // Aqui deberia estar el ajax de tu codigo
      // con tus parametros
      // Esto es solo un ajax de prueba
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ){
            $('.reponse')
            .html('') /* Reseteamos*/
            .append('<p>CC NO es activado</p>')
            .append('<p>'+ clientID +' es la ID del client</p>')
            .append('<p>Respuesta del AJAX:</p>')
            .append(JSON.stringify( response ))
        }
      })
    
    }
    
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="client">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cc">
  <input type="submit" id="send" value="enviar">
</form>

<div class="reponse"></div>
```

Espero que sea correcta la respuesta a tu pregunta.